# json produced by django serializer is not getting rendered in angular ui grid

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, angular-ui-grid

angular ui-grid is not able to show the json produced by my view which is as follows:

```
class DummyResponse(APIView):



     def get(self, request, pk, format='None'):
         GuestEntryModel = get_model('buddy', 'GuestEntry')
         print "GuestEntryModel.objects.all",GuestEntryModel.objects.all()
         serialized_data = serializers.serialize("json", GuestEntryModel.objects.all(),fields=('model'))
         print "serialized_data::",serialized_data
         return Response(serialized_data)
```

json produced from this view is like this:

```
"[{\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry\", \"pk\": 1}, {\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry
\", \"pk\": 2}, {\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry\", \"pk\": 3}, {\"fields\": {}, \"model
\": \"buddy.guestentry\", \"pk\": 4}, {\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry\", \"pk\": 5}, 
{\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry\", \"pk\": 6}, {\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry
\", \"pk\": 7}, {\"fields\": {}, \"model\": \"buddy.guestentry\", \"pk\": 8}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show your Angular code, I think in time when you get data you must iterate trough that data and put it in variable, like in example below

```
$scope.posts = [];
$http.get('/api/posts').then(function (result) {
    angular.forEach result.data, function (item) {
        $scope.posts.push( item);
    }
}
```